# How to get a text content to a variable of a cell using onclick

Tags: javascript

This is the example of what I have, and now what I want is to get the information if the row is checked or not. The information should saved as a boolean variable which name is the same as a text in first column of a highlighted row

```js
window.onload = highlight();

function highlight(){
 var table = document.getElementById('myTab1');
  for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
   table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
    var flag = false;
    if(this.className == 'check-tr'){
     this.className = 'check-tr-checked';
     flag = true;
    }
    if(this.className == 'check-tr-checked' && flag == false){
     this.className = 'check-tr';
    }  
   }
   }
}
```

```css
.check-td{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 8px;
 border: 1px solid;
 min-width:100px;
}

.check-tr .check-td{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding: 8px;
 border: 1px solid;
 min-width:100px;
}

.check-tr:hover .check-td{
 background: #ddd; 
}

.check-tr-checked .check-td{
 background-color: #ababad;
 padding: 8px;
 border: 1px solid;
 min-width:100px;
}

.check-tr-checked:hover .check-td{
 background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTab1" style="width:90%">
  <thead>
   <td class="report-th" colspan="2">
    Reports
   </td>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr class="check-tr">
      <td class="check-td">
        a
      </td>
            <td class="check-td">
                1
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="check-tr">
      <td class="check-td">
        b
      </td>
            <td class="check-td">
                2
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="check-tr">
      <td class="check-td">
        c
      </td>
            <td class="check-td">
                3
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="check-tr">
      <td class="check-td">
        d
      </td>
            <td class="check-td">
                4
             </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a part of my html project which uses JavaScript to check and uncheck rows in table (changing their class)

```
window.onload = highlight();

function highlight{
    var table = document.getElementById('myTab1');
        for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
            table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
                alert(this.content);
                var flag = false;
                if(this.className == 'check-tr'){
                    this.className = 'check-tr-checked';
                    flag = true;
                }
                if(this.className == 'check-tr-checked' && flag == false){
                    this.className = 'check-tr';
                }       
            }
        }
}
```

I want to store the text of the first cell from the row that was clicked to a variable. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: `window.onload = highlight`

Comment: @K.Zdzioch: If it "worked anyway" as your now-deleted comment said, then you've got your `script` tags in the right place (good!) and there's no need for the `window.onload =` part, just call `highlight();`

Comment: The question conflicts with itself. Do you want to store all the text in the table to a variable? Or the text on the clicked row only? Or on the clicked cell? The title says "cell", the text says "table", I said "row" ...

Comment: Please provide a working example - shouldn't be too hard and will make it easy to understand your problem. Btw. did you try using the innerHTML? property?

Comment: Yes, I deleted it 'cause it turned out that it didn't... Ok thank's. I'm quite new to this so lot of things may be wrong, or unnecessary

Comment: @Teemu : To be exact I want to store text of the first cell from the row that was clicked.

Comment: @K.Kirsz : I'll provide it in a moment. No I didn't

Comment: In the click handler `this.firstElementChild` refers to the first cell on a row. `textContent` gives you the plain text, `innerHTML` will give you all the HTML within the cell, including text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = highlight();

function highlight(){ //added paranthesis here
    var table = document.getElementById('myTab1');
        for (var i=0;i < table.rows.length;i++){
            table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
                alert(this.innerText);
                var flag = false;
                if(this.className == 'check-tr'){
                    this.className = 'check-tr-checked';
                    flag = true;
                }
                if(this.className == 'check-tr-checked' && flag == false){
                    this.className = 'check-tr';
                }       
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. Not a  very hard problem, but as I said I'm new to this and I couldn't find that simple solution onlline. That should do